# How to reverse lines inside repeated blocks in a text file (using sed/awk?)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, command-line

I have a file like this:

```
x = {
   y = {
       z = {
           block = {
              line1
              line2
              line3
           }
        }
    }
}
x2 = {
     y2 = {
         block = {
              line4
              line5
         }
     }
}
xyz
block = {
      line6
}
```

and so on. I need to reverse lines within block but everything else should stay in order, like this:

```
x = {
   y = {
       z = {
           block = {
              line3
              line2
              line1
           }
        }
    }
}
x2 = {
     y2 = {
         block = {
              line5
              line4
              
         }
     }
}
xyz
block = {
      line6
}
```

How do I do that with sed or awk? I managed to get the blocks reversed but I can't fit them back into place:

```
sed -n '/block = {.$/,/}$/p' inputfile | tac
```

Comment: WIth GNU `sed`, the `R` command could be used to reintegrate lines that have previously been written in a file, but unfortunally piping the whole filtered lines to `tac` doesn't do what you what (reverse blockwise). For a `sed` solution, you should do it in one pass using the hold space, like shown in my answer. Think of the lines as a stack of paper. You turn one page after another, but those belonging to a block go to a separate stack (the hold space) first. After the block you turn the separate stack together, resulting in a reversed order of those pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are okay with Perl:

```bash
perl -ne 'if($f && /}/){$f=0; print @blk};
          $f ? unshift(@blk, $_) : print;
          if(/block = {/){$f=1; @blk=()}' ip.txt
```

- `if(/block = {/){$f=1; @blk=()}` initializes `@blk` array and sets the flag `$f` if input line contains `block = {`
- `$f ? unshift(@blk, $_) : print` if the flag is active, insert input line at the front of the `@blk` array, otherwise print the input line
- `if($f && /}/){$f=0; print @blk}` if the flag is active and input line contains `}`, then unset the flag and print the contents of `@blk` array

With `awk`:

```bash
awk 'f && /}/{f=0; for(i=c; i>=1; i--) print blk[i]}
     {if(f) blk[++c] = $0; else print}
     /block = {/{f=1; c=0}' ip.txt
```

Comment: why do you need to escape the opening brace in `/block = \{/` but not the closing brace in `f && /}/`

Comment: Seems like I did it out of habit similar to `(` metacharacter. Just checked for `{` and seems it isn't necessary for both Perl and Awk when it doesn't conflict as a quantifier.

Comment: @farraget `}` is only a metacharacter if it follows an unescaped `{` so the only time you need to escape `}` is if it follows `{` but you want it treated literally, in the same way that `)` and `]` are only metachars when they follow `(` and `[` respectively. `{`, `(`, and `[`, on the other hand, ARE metachars unless escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Another `perl` approach, relying on indentation to find the closing `}` for a corresponding `block = {`:

```
perl -C -0777 -pe '
  s{^(\h*)block = \{\n\K.*?\n(?=\1\}$)}{
    join "", reverse $& =~ m{.*\n}g
  }gems' < your-file
```

Answer (score 2):

Proving that `sed` code can be easy to write, but hard to read:

```
sed '/block = {/,/}/{/[{}]/!{G;h;d;};x;s/.$//p;g;s/.*//;x;}' file
```

The concept is to collect the lines to be reversed (those without braces) in the hold space by appending the current hold space (so the order is changed automatically). The code is portable, working with any `sed` implementation. In detail:

- `/block = {/,/}/` selects each range from `block = {` to the next `}`, like you did yourself. All other code like the `xyz` is printed without change
- `/[{}]/!{G;h;d;}` handles the lines without braces (the block lines): `G` appends the current hold space, `h` moves the result to the hold space and `d` stops processing for that line with output
- The rest is executed for brace lines only. That's where the lines from the hold space need to be printed by `x`changing buffers, then `s/.$//p` to remove the trailing newline in the hold space that was introduced by appending to an empty hold space. The `p` option to the `s`ubstitude command prints only on a successful substitution to avoid printing an empty hold space. Finally use `g` to restore the current line from the hold space
- Finally we need to empty the hold space: `s/.*//;x`: save the current line to `h`old space, empty the pattern space and exchange buffers, so the hold space will be empty, while the pattern space contains the current line again for output.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I added the filter for the block, like you already used in your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
inBlock {
    if ( $1 == "}" ) {
        $0 = block $0
        block = inBlock = ""
    }
    else {
        block = $0 ORS block
    }
}
!inBlock
$1 == "block" {
    inBlock = 1
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
x = {
   y = {
       z = {
           block = {
              line3
              line2
              line1
           }
        }
    }
}
x2 = {
     y2 = {
         block = {
              line5
              line4
         }
     }
}
xyz
block = {
      line6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @blk; if (/block/ && .put) { for lines() {
             if /\}/  { put join "\n", (@blk.pop xx @blk.elems, $_); last};  
             @blk.push: $_ }
             } else { .put };'   file

#OR (more simply)

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @blk; if (/block/ & .put) { for lines() { 
             if /\}/ { .put for (@blk.pop xx @blk.elems, $_).flat; last};  
             @blk.push: $_ }
             };'  file
```

The code above is written in Raku, a Perl-family language. Input is read linewise with the `-ne` non-autoprinting flags. Within a `BEGIN` block, a `@blk` array is declared, and `if` the "block" string (keyword) is encountered, `lines` are read up to a final `}` closing curlie brace. As they are read, `lines` are `push`ed onto the `@blk` array, and `pop`ped off entirely (i.e. in reverse order) when the `}` closing curlie is at `last` found.

Sample Input:

```
x = {
   y = {
       z = {
           block = {
              line1
              line2
              line3
           }
        }
    }
}
x2 = {
     y2 = {
         block = {
              line4
              line5
         }
     }
}
xyz
block = {
      line6
}
```

Sample Output:

```
x = {
   y = {
       z = {
           block = {
              line3
              line2
              line1
           }
        }
    }
}
x2 = {
     y2 = {
         block = {
              line5
              line4
         }
     }
}
xyz
block = {
      line6
}
```

---

Addendum: For anyone seeking a Raku translation of @Sundeep's excellent Perl5 solution, here it is:

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @blk; state $f; 
             if ($f && /\}/) {$f=0; .put for @blk}; 
             $f ?? unshift(@blk, $_) !! .put; 
             if (/block/) {$f=1; @blk=()};'  file
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](https://www.nongnu.org/txr) solution:

```
$ txr data.txr data
x = {
   y = {
       z = {
           block = {
              line3
              line2
              line1
           }
        }
    }
}
x2 = {
     y2 = {
         block = {
              line5
              line4
         }
     }
}
xyz
block = {
      line6
}
```

Code:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@{indent}block = {
@    (collect)
@      lines
@    (last)
@{indent}}
@    (end)
@    (do (upd lines reverse))
@    (output)
@{indent}block = {
@      (repeat)
@        lines
@      (end)
@{indent}}
@    (end)
@  (or)
@    line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Here is what that looks like in vim, using the official syntax definitions from the TXR project. You can see that the TXR directives are colored differently from Lisp functions and operators (in this scheme, yellow versus green).  The variables are colored differently from those two (blue), and the literal text being matched or output stays white.

[image: With syntax highlighting via Vim]

Explanation:

```
@(repeat)
...
@(end)
```

This construct scans the input in a line-oriented way, looking for matches for its interior `...` expression. `@(repeat)` is a syntactic sugar for `@(collect :vars ())`. It an idiom used when input is scanned in order to perpetrate some side effect, rather than just to perform matching and produce pattern variable bindings.

Inside the `repeat` we have two `cases`:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
...
@  (or)
...
@  (end)
@(end)
```

The first case looks for the `block = {` blocks terminated by a closing brace at the same indentation level. If that doesn't match, then the fallback second case just matches one line and outputs it.

The fallback case is trivial:

```
@    line
@    (do (put-line line))
```

`@(do ...)` is used to embed Lisp code into TXR, usually some kind of side effect. `@line` has captured the entire line, and we send that off to the `put-line` function to have it printed immediately.

The main case for recognizing blocks is more complicated. The pattern matching first half of it is this:

```
@{indent}block = {
@    (collect)
@      lines
@    (last)
@{indent}}
@    (end)
```

First, we match a line which consists of some arbitrary material that is captured into the `indent` variable, followed by the `block = {` ending. In the given input, `indent` always matches spaces.

After that, we have a `collect` which collects every line. This is terminated when a match occurs in the `last` subclause: a line is encountered which consists of the `indent`, and a closing brace. This terminating line is excluded from the `collect` body match, but consumed.

The next item in the case is a side effect to reverse the lines in place:

```
@    (do (upd lines reverse))
```

We can do this any number of ways, including binding a new variable (avoiding a side effect). I used the `upd` macro which updates a variable in place after filtering it through a chain of functions. For instance if `x` contains `1`, then `(upd x succ (* 3))` will update `x` by taking the successor value `2`, then multiplying it by `3` to get `6`, and storing that `6` back into `x`.

The last part of the `block = {` processing case is to output the transformed block:

```
@    (output)
@{indent}block = {
@      (repeat)
@        lines
@      (end)
@{indent}}
@    (end)
```

We output a line consisting of the `indent` followed by `block = {`, then the reversed lines, and then a terminating line consisting of the `indent` and a closing brace.